# Extracting XML document in XML node from WCF-SQL message using body path expression

Tags: xml, wcf, xpath, biztalk

I am receiving a message from an SQL server in WCF-SQL adapter. In this message there is an XML node, which contains a fully formatted XML document as a string. What I need, is to extract only this document, ignoring the rest of the body, so that it can be processed further by a pipeline.

I've tried a bunch of xPath expressions in the "body path expression" input field in the config settings on the adapter, but none of them seems to work the way i expect.

Some xPath strings I've tried:

```
    /Polling/PolledData[1]/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data' and local-name()='DataSet'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' and local-name()='diffgram'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='NewDataSet'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='NewTable'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='msgbody'][1]

    /*[local-name()='Polling']/*[local-name()='PolledData']/*[local-name()='DataSet']/*[local-name()='diffgram']/*[local-name()='NewDataSet']/*[local-name()='NewTable']/*[local-name()='msgbody']

    /Polling/PolledData/DataSet/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/NewTable/msgbody

    //*[msgbody]/text()
```

The body of the XML document I receive is structured like so, with the XML node I am trying to extract content from at the end:

```
<Polling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Polling/">
    <PolledData>
        <DataSet xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NewTable">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="conversationID" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hostUTC" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgType" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="acknowledgment" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sendLog" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgFormat" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgbody" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fromID" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="toID" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                    <NewTable>
                        <conversationID>b4327577-14d1-478d-9e22-027683c0c5f9</conversationID>
                        <hostUTC>2018-11-19T13:17:07.03Z</hostUTC>
                        <msgType>INVOIC</msgType>
                        <msgFormat>oioUBL</msgFormat>
                        <msgbody>&lt;Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

I'm unsure how to properly write the correct xPath to this node. Reading the documention on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/specifying-the-message-body-for-the-wcf-adapters#specifying-how-the-biztalk-message-body-is-extracted-from-an-incoming-soap-message) seems to indicate that I need to use the local-name syntax. I think my problem lies in the use of namespaces in the received XML, but I don't know how to include these in the xPath.

Comment: Did you try to just get the whole message into biztalk without setting the body xpath. Then manually test your body xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first XPath was nearly right, except you were missing the namespaces from it for the first two nodes.

Also the `[1]`'s in your first your XPath examples are necessary unless there are multiple nodes and you wish to select the first one.

The correct Xpath would be

```
/*[local-name()='Polling' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Polling/']
/*[local-name()='PolledData' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Polling/']
/*[local-name()='DataSet' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data']
/*[local-name()='diffgram' and namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1']
/*[local-name()='NewDataSet' and namespace-uri()='']
/*[local-name()='NewTable' and namespace-uri()='']
/*[local-name()='msgbody' and namespace-uri()='']
```

But I you might still have an issue as it looks like the rest of your payload has been escaped, e.g. the < is a `&lt;`

Comment: Thank you so much! This returned the expected content from the node. Biztalk seems to automatically convert the escaped characters to the corresponding XML tags.