# How do I use the WCF-CustomIsolated base64 decoding in BizTalk?

Tags: wcf, xpath, base64, biztalk

**Input**
An xml with a root and a base64-encoded xml, like `<data>FFEFE#13DD</data>`.

**Problem**
On the Message tab in the WCF-CustomIsolated adapter you can choose a body path expression to point to the postion in the incoming message you want to use as message. You can also set the type, string, xml, hex or base64.

Setting up this, with a tested xpath, using allowed syntax, that points to an Element and base64 as type, and make a SOAP-call from Postman ends up in "*System.InvalidOperationException: ReadSubtree() can be called only if the reader is on an element node.*" To me it sounds like the xpath is not correct, but it is :)

I've looked at [Extracting XML with WCF-SQL adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390957/extracting-xml-document-in-xml-node-from-wcf-sql-message-using-body-path-express) and believe I do like that. Does anyone have used this functionality and can guide me? I would be most grateful.

Comment: You can refer to the configuration steps in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-configure-a-wcf-customisolated-receive-location) to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Thank you @Jiayao. I forgot to mention I have read MS documentation, but when you now pointed to it I read it says that InboundBodyLocation only applies on Solicit-Response ports. That can be the reason, since my is static oneway, but if so I wonder why it acts on my configuration? I understand why OutboundBodyLocation only applies to solicit-response, but think it's unfortunate if it also applies to InboundBodyLocation.

Comment: As the doc says, this property is valid only for solicit-response ports. And according to the error message, the ReadSubtree method can only be used on the element node, which means that it can only access the xml element and not the entire xml document. This is useful if you are passing data to another component for processing and you want to limit the amount of data that component can access.